# Reading cross domain csv file using JSONP and AJAX

Tags: ajax, csv, jsonp

Trying to read cross domain csv file :

```
remote_url = “http://www.example.com/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&columnlist=bug_id%2Cshort_desc&query_format=advanced&ctype=csv";
$.ajax({
    url:remote_url,
    type:"get",

    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",                     
    success:function(data){    
        console.log(data);                
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);  
    }
});
```

Although getting 200 status from server, It always going into error callback handler and logging a JavaScript syntax error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement 6230,"this is a ""short description"", blah blah blah..

My CSV file has two columns “bug_id” and “short_desc” with following values:

```
bug_id = 6230
short_desc = this is a "short description", blah blah blah..
```

I know the error is because of double quote in description, but I don’t know the solution. I tried “YQL” to convert CSV to JSON but it returned `null` as a result, may be because of an error.

Answer (score 0):

The JSONP technique expects the response to be JavaScript. This is why you're getting a JavaScript error; it's trying to execute the CSV content as JavaScript.

JSONP works by defining a callback function in the server, adding a script tag with a URL that tells the server what function it will call, then the server responds with JavaScript that calls that function with the data as a parameter.

The destination URL must support this protocol in other words. You can't just use JSONP for any arbitrary request.

You may need to use a different technique to get your data, like a same-domain proxy that does the HTTP request to the server. If you are able to change the code at `example.com`, you have even more options.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am not allowed to change the code at example.com

Comment: You should treat the file as what it is then: CSV. Parse it, as you need it, or search S.O. for javascript csv parsing.